# Which namespace is necessary to use SelectSingleNode() method (using default namespace and can't use the method)

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, msxml, selectsinglenode

Hi I have xml file (which is actually msbuild file) that uses different namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(key)'=='1111'">
          <Key>Value</Key>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But the problem is I can't use SelectSingleNode with that file because of

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
```

I believe it's since default namespace (necessary for the method) is gone because of xmlns above. Then I think I just need to add necessary one for that.. But my tries weren't successful at all. Could you please give me a quick example how to do this?

Here is how I did. (I also tried to added multiple namespaces but weren't successful..)

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("ref.props");        
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("msbld", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

XmlNode platform_node
  = xml.SelectSingleNode("//msbld:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition, '1111')]", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the *correct* namespace, which *is* "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`".

Try

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load("ref.props");        
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ms", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003");

XmlNode platform_node
  = xml.SelectSingleNode("/ms:Project/ms:PropertyGroup[contains(@Condition, '1111')]",
                         nsmgr);
```

Don't confuse the namespace prefix (which was empty in the XML) with the namespace, which is "`http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003`".

Comment: Try removing the `[contains]` and see if you get anything.

Comment: I got 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error when I removed contains..

Comment: What line did you get that on? I bet it was after your SelectSingleNode.

Comment: oh.. yeah it was after SelectSingleNode! sorry about this

Comment: Can I ask one more question? I need to get a child node of that property group. but name of child node is dynamic that I can't just append name in xpath query. But I have a string variable that contains name of child node. Then, in this case how should I write xpath query so that I can query only within parent node and using string variable?

Comment: One question per question, please. Ask a separate question.

Comment: Ah.. okay.. sorry about that