# How to ignore a XML namespace

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have an XML file and this XML file has namespaces declared

```
<CrystalReport  xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
```

This is causing problems in my VBA code in Excel. When I remove the namespaces of this line above, it works fine.

**My question is: How can I ignore this namespace without have to open the xml file and remove manually?**

The code I am using:

```
Public xmlDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Public Sub setXML(xmlFileName As String)

    'Set xmlDOM = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xmlDOM = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDOM.async = False
    xmlDOM.Load xmlFileName

End Sub

Public Function getNode(p_strNode As Variant) As Variant

    Dim objNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim objNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim storage As Variant
    Dim X As Integer

    Set objNodes = xmlDOM.SelectNodes(p_strNode)

    Set getNode = objNodes

End Function

Public Sub SB_StartLoadClarityReport()

    Dim d_path As String
    Dim d_node As Variant
    Dim d_arrayFields As Variant

    d_path = F_GetPathXML()

    '@Temp
    d_path = Cells(1, 1).Value

    'Open XML File
    setXML (d_path)

    'Get the project fields
    Set d_node = getNode("CrystalReport/Details/Section")
    d_arrayFields = F_GetProjectFields(d_node)

End Sub

Private Function F_GetProjectFields(p_strNode As Variant)

    'Get the project fields
    'Ex: <Field Name="PROJECTNAME1" - Get PROJECTNAME1

    Dim d_arrayFields As Variant
    Dim p_item As IXMLDOMElement
    Dim d_count As Integer

    d_count = 1

    For Each p_item In p_strNode.Item(0).ChildNodes

        If d_count = 1 Then
            ReDim d_arrayFields(1 To d_count)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve d_arrayFields(1 To d_count)
        End If

        d_arrayFields(d_count) = p_item.Attributes.Item(0).Text
        d_count = d_count + 1

    Next p_item

    F_GetProjectFields = d_arrayFields

End Function
```

Comment: We don't know your VBA code so we are unable to help.

Comment: Hi Reporter. I just edited my post and added the code I am using. Remember that as I said, without the namespace in the XML, the code runs without any problem.

Comment: Maybe try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490839/how-to-query-default-namespace-with-msxml

Comment: Hi Tim! I think it can be a solution. I am trying to use setProperty in VBA but I am getting code error: xmlDOM.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'")

Comment: I am trying to using the answers given in that post which is to use a prefix, but it's not working too :/

Comment: I tried, tried and tried and I couldn't make it work :/ Does anyone have a solution about this. I can't make this namespace work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me (after some amount of head-scratching)

```
Sub Tester()

    Const XML As String = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" & _
    "<CrystalReport  xmlns='urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail' " & _
    " xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " & _
    " xsi:schemaLocation='urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail " & _
    " http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd'>" & _
    "   <Test>Testing</Test>" & _
    "</CrystalReport>"

    Dim xmlDom As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim iNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    With xmlDom
        .async = False
        .validateOnParse = True
        .LoadXML XML
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

        'set the default namespace and give it a prefix (e.g.) "xx"
        .setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
                     "xmlns:xx='urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail'"

        'use the same default prefix in your XPath
        Set nodeList = .SelectNodes("//xx:Test")

    End With

    Debug.Print nodeList.Length
    For Each iNode In nodeList
        Debug.Print iNode.XML
    Next iNode

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, I changed set code like your wrote and it worked perfectly! I am studing these commands you showed to understand better now. Thanks a lot Tim!

Comment: The SelectionLanguage setting should be unnecessary; according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754679(v=vs.85)#remarks ... "For MSXML 4.0 and later, only a value of "XPath" is recognized as XPath is the only query language supported and therefore, this property can be ignored."

Answer (score 2):

I spent a few hours trying to find a proper solution that ignores any namespace, without having to set them in `.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces"`, because I didn't want to change my `.SelectNodes("//Test")` code to match every possible namespace !

The solution that worked for me requires using the method `.transformNodeToObject`  :

```
Public Sub fixNS(ByRef doc As DOMDocument60)
  Dim fixNS0 As New DOMDocument60
  fixNS0.LoadXML ("<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>" & _
    "<xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes' encoding='UTF-8' omit-xml-declaration='yes' />" & _
    "<xsl:template match='comment()'> <xsl:copy/> </xsl:template>" & _
    "<xsl:template match='*'>" & _
        "<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>" & _
        "<xsl:element name='{local-name(.)}'>" & _
            "<xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>" & _
        "</xsl:element>" & _
        "<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>" & _
    "</xsl:template> <xsl:template match='@*'>" & _
        "<xsl:attribute name='{local-name(.)}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></xsl:attribute>" & _
    "</xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>")
  doc.transformNodeToObject fixNS0, doc
End Sub
```

The provided `xsl:stylesheet` removes all namespaces, while preserving attributes and also comments, but you can change it to remove them.
Now I'm using my initial code `.SelectNodes("//Test")` without worrying about any namespace I load !

**EDIT**
After some research, I managed to modify the xsl:stylesheet to keep indentation, as the original code was just stacking elements one after another, so adding 2 Line Feed characters before and after the element tag (like `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>`) solved the issue.

---

**Notes**

- A reference to `Microsoft XML, v6.0` is required to use the code.
- You can save the whole *< xsl >* code to an external file `.xsl` and use the *`.load "file.xsl"`* method instead, but I prefer it this way to be as much standalone as possible !
- The resulting xml indentation is now like the original, but if you don't like the closing `<tags></tags>` issue, you'll need to use this *PrettyPrintXML* function to get `<tags/>` :

  ```
   Public Function PrettyPrintXML(XML As String) As String
     Dim Reader As New SAXXMLReader60, Writer As New MXXMLWriter60
     Writer.indent = True: Writer.standalone = False
     Writer.omitXMLDeclaration = True: Writer.Encoding = "utf-8"

     Set Reader.contentHandler = Writer: Set Reader.dtdHandler = Writer
     Set Reader.errorHandler = Writer

     Call Reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", Writer)
     Call Reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", Writer)
     Call Reader.parse(XML) 'A document must contain exactly one root element
     PrettyPrintXML = Writer.output
   End Function
  ```
- To check if a change is needed, you can verify that :
  `xmlDom.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI <> ""`

Comment: Nicely done +:) Instead of a SAXXMLReader60 reference to get indentation you might try *Pretty Print Raw Output* used by Parfait e.g.  in post [create xml using DOM in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634134/create-xml-using-dom-in-vba/37634549#37634549)

Comment: @T.M. I tried that _PrettyPrint_ and got identical output, but since I'm not very familiar with XSLT, I couldn't combine the 2 transformations in one go (remove xmlns + PrettyPrint), I just collected the code from different answers and put it in one simple function to use later as a one-liner, and since I'm dealing with xml nodes and attributes, the reference is already added anyway.

Comment: I fixed the indentation issue, but got the `<tags></tags>`  vs `<tags/>` issue, which only my initial *PrettyPrintXML* function could solve, so I'll stick with it !