# Create XML using DOM in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, dom

Hi Struggling with VBA code. I am using Microsoft XML V6.0 dom object:

I need following xml to be created exactly:

```
<UserAccountDetail Type="Account">
    <AccountName>
        <Name>rkhan@gmail.com</Name>
        <Pwd>kdfslj</Pwd>
        <Status>N</Status>
        <ClientId>kdjslj</ClientId>
        <ClientSecret>dkfjsl</ClientSecret>
    </AccountName>
</UserAccountDetail>
```

Here is my Code so far:

```vb
' Create a processing instruction targeted for xml.
    Set node = dom.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version='1.0'")
    dom.appendChild node
    Set node = Nothing
    
    ' Create a comment for the document.
    Set node = dom.createComment("sample xml file created using XML DOM object.")
    dom.appendChild node
    Set node = Nothing
    
    ' Create the root element.
    
    Set root = dom.createElement("AccountName")
    ' Create a "created" attribute for the root element and
    ' assign the "using dom" character data as the attribute value.
    Set attr = dom.createAttribute("Type")
    attr.Value = "Account"
    root.setAttributeNode attr
    Set attr = Nothing
    
    ' Add the root element to the DOM instance.
    dom.appendChild root
    ' Add a newline plus tab.
    root.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    ' Create a text element Account Name.
    Set node = dom.createElement("Name")
    node.Text = Trim(UserName)
    ' Add text node to the root element.
    dom.getElementsByTagName("AccountName")(0).appendChild node
    Set node = Nothing
    
    ' Create a text element Password.
    'root(0).appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = dom.createElement("Pwd")
    node.Text = Trim(UserPwd)
    ' Add text node to the root element.
    dom.getElementsByTagName("AccountName")(0).appendChild node
    node.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = Nothing
    
    ' Create a text element Status.
    'root(0).appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = dom.createElement("Status")
    node.Text = Trim(Status)
    ' Add text node to the root element.
    dom.getElementsByTagName("AccountName")(0).appendChild node
    node.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = Nothing
    
    ' Create a text element Client Id.
    'root(0).appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = dom.createElement("ClientId")
    node.Text = Trim(strClientId)
    ' Add text node to the root element.
    dom.getElementsByTagName("AccountName")(0).appendChild node
    node.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = Nothing
    
    ' Create a text element Client Secret.
    'root(0).appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = dom.createElement("ClientSecret")
    node.Text = Trim(strClientSecret)
    ' Add text node to the root element.
    dom.getElementsByTagName("AccountName")(0).appendChild node
    node.appendChild dom.createTextNode(vbNewLine + vbTab)
    Set node = Nothing
```

Comment: Just look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118576/how-can-i-pretty-print-xml-source-using-vb6-and-msxml

Answer (score 4):

Using VBA's MSXML object to create an XML document will not automatically *pretty print* output with indentation. To resolve, run an [identity transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) XSLT just after creating and processing your `dom` object with child elements. Fortunately, MSXML can run XSLT 1.0 scripts:

```
Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'...same code to build XML document...'

' PRETTY PRINT RAW OUTPUT '
xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
        & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
        & "                xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
        & "<xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
        & "<xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
        & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
        & " <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
        & "  <xsl:copy>" _
        & "   <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
        & "  </xsl:copy>" _
        & " </xsl:template>" _
        & "</xsl:stylesheet>"

xslDoc.async = False     
dom.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
newDoc.Save ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Output.xml"
```