# VBA with XSLT to pretty print XML with end tags in the same line

Tags: xml, vba, xslt, msxml

```
<Root ID="123"   Name="Board">
    <Element1 name="AAA"/>
    <Element2 name="BBB"/>
    <Element3 name="CCC"/>
    <Element4 name="DDD" Age="56" Address="78"/>
    <Nested_Elements>
      <Nested Number="125"/>
      <Nested Number="250"/>
      <Nested Number="500"/>
      <Nested Number="1000"/>
    </Nested_Elements>
</Root>
```

I wrote VBA code to export the XML and use the XSLT style to pretty print it by adding this

```
    Set xslDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
xslDoc.LoadXML "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & "?>" _
        & "<xsl:stylesheet version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) _
        & "                xmlns:xsl=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" & Chr(34) & ">" _
        & "  <xsl:strip-space elements=" & Chr(34) & "*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
        & "  <xsl:output method=" & Chr(34) & "xml" & Chr(34) & " indent=" & Chr(34) & "yes" & Chr(34) & "" _
        & "            encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "/>" _
        & "  <xsl:template match=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & ">" _
        & "    <xsl:copy>" _
        & "       <xsl:apply-templates select=" & Chr(34) & "node() | @*" & Chr(34) & " />" _
        & "    </xsl:copy>" _
        & "  </xsl:template>" _
        & "</xsl:stylesheet>"
xslDoc.async = False
Set XmlNewDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
XDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, XmlNewDoc   'Line to fix indention
XmlNewDoc.Save XmlFile
```

The problem is this will add extra end tags like this

```
<Root ID="123"   Name="Board">
<Element1 name="AAA">
</Element1>
<Element2 name="BBB">
</Element2>
<Element3 name="CCC">
</Element3>
<Element4 name="DDD" Age="56" Address="78">
</Element4>
<Nested_Elements>
  <Nested Number="125">
  </Nested>
  <Nested Number="250">
  </Nested>
  <Nested Number="500">
  </Nested>
  <Nested Number="1000">
  </Nested>
</Nested_Elements>
```

I know it shouldn't be any diffrent from XML poit of view ,but I need the files to have the same structures as old files for configuration managment problems,

Any Idea how to change  it to produce the same end tags?

Comment: Does the use of `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0` instead of `MSXML2.DOMDocument` change the formatting?

Comment: Don't see the 'extra end tags' problem - can you be more specific?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the problem, that the serializer uses a start and an end tag for the element markup or the white space introduced between the start and an end tag of elements that were previously empty? I don't think the serializer should insert the white space into empty elements when indenting but otherwise `<foo/>` and `<foo></foo>` are indeed the same in XML and it will be hard to ensure with most tools that the short, closed start tag form is the preferred one.

Comment: Sorry for not bieng clear enough ,yes the problem is I want this  <foo/> but it gives this format  <foo></foo>  .. I know it is still the same thing ,but would prefer to keep the same formatting of the file ,for version control .

Comment: I don't remember any setting for MSXML, in the .NET DOM XmlElement has https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty?view=net-5.0 which is supposed to ensure serialization as `<foo/>`. Not sure whether Word or Office these days make it easy to call into .NET instead of using VBA.

Comment: Yes ,I cannot find the isEmpty() with MSXML ,but I thought maybe there is a way with XSLT and transformNodeToObject  ? No ?

Comment: I don't recall any way, I have taken the liberty to add a tag for msxml to your question, perhaps that way someone still being familiar with all its details can give you a definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with XSLT to remove namespaces here [How to ignore an XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75665800/8289977), I managed to prettyPrint the output, but still got those annoying `<tag></tag>` for empty tags, so I still rely on my initial function I used, and here it is for anyone facing the same issue (you only need to add a reference to `Microsoft XML, v6.0`) :

```
Public Function PrettyPrintXML(XML As String) As String
  Dim Reader As New SAXXMLReader60, Writer As New MXXMLWriter60
  Writer.indent = True: Writer.standalone = False
  Writer.omitXMLDeclaration = True: Writer.Encoding = "utf-8"

  Set Reader.contentHandler = Writer: Set Reader.dtdHandler = Writer: Set Reader.errorHandler = Writer

  Call Reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler", Writer)
  Call Reader.putProperty("http://xml.org/sax/properties/lexical-handler", Writer)
  Call Reader.parse(XML) 'A document must contain exactly one root element
  PrettyPrintXML = Writer.output
End Function
```

This will take care of indentation as well as self-closing `<tags />`, unlike the other solution [Create XML using DOM in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37634549/8289977) by @Parfait which does prettyPrint the xml, but doesn't solve the closing tags issue.

Answer (score 5):

Consider an alternative XSLT 1.0 processor if the MSXML version renders the undesired closing tags. One freely available version that ships with most Windows machines is NET's [XslCompiledTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=net-5.0).

This class can be accessed and run via a Powershell script which in turn can be run at command line or by Excel with `Shell` command. This XSLT version will render self-closing tags.

**Input** *(save as Input.xml)*

```xml
<Root ID="123"   Name="Board">
<Element1 name="AAA">
</Element1>
<Element2 name="BBB">
</Element2>
<Element3 name="CCC">
</Element3>
<Element4 name="DDD" Age="56" Address="78">
</Element4>
<Nested_Elements>
  <Nested Number="125">
  </Nested>
  <Nested Number="250">
  </Nested>
  <Nested Number="500">
  </Nested>
  <Nested Number="1000">
  </Nested>
</Nested_Elements>
</Root>
```

**XSLT** *(save as style.xsl)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Powershell** *(save as run_xslt.ps1 file)*

```
# Load the style sheet.
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
$xslt.Load("C:\Path\To\style.xsl");

# Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
$xslt.Transform("C:\Path\To\input.xml", "C:\Path\To\output.xml");
```

**VBA** *(blue screen should pop up with any error or output message)*

```vb
Sub RunXSLT()
    Dim RetVal As Variant
    
    RetVal = Shell("Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noexit -File " & _
                   """C:\Path\To\run_xslt.ps1""", 1)
End Sub
```

**Output** *(Output.xml)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root ID="123" Name="Board">
  <Element1 name="AAA" />
  <Element2 name="BBB" />
  <Element3 name="CCC" />
  <Element4 name="DDD" Age="56" Address="78" />
  <Nested_Elements>
    <Nested Number="125" />
    <Nested Number="250" />
    <Nested Number="500" />
    <Nested Number="1000" />
  </Nested_Elements>
</Root>
```

Comment: Nice & highly interesting to learn this PowerShell approach +:)